# Sum values of specific columns of two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to sum specific columns of two dataframe.

eg :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1], 'b': [1,1,1], 'c':['dd','ee','ff'], 'd':[1,1,1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1], 'b': [1,1,1], 'c':['dd','ee','ff'], 'd':[1,1,1]})
```

so i want to sum only column a,b and d not c.

output :

```
a b c  d

2 2 dd 2

2 2 ee 2

2 3 ff 2
```

Any solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: You want the sum of column a, column b, column c. Correct ?

Comment: @PrashantKumar : yes, i want to sum df1[a] with df2[a] and so on..

Comment: noticed your final row has 3 for the b column. I believe it should be 2. you could check your data again to be sure.

Comment: Check the updated answer. That should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the add method, and [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) method to get the result. The [select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) allows operations based on the data type.

```
(df1
.add(df2.select_dtypes(include='number'))
.combine_first(df1)
)

    a   b   c   d
0   2   2   dd  2
1   2   2   ee  2
2   2   2   ff  2
```

Comment: this solution is perfect if the column has numeric value, does it work if i read data from csv file..?

Comment: yes it does. you can also ensure the data type is assured by using the dtype option in the read_csv function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#specifying-categorical-dtype

Comment: yes, i just run the demo and got the correct output.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
column_names = df1.columns.tolist()

columnTotal_dict = {}

for name in colum_names:
    try:
        df1[[name]] = df1[[name]].astype(int)
        df2[[name]] = df2[[name]].astype(int)

        sumCol_a_df1 = df1['a'].sum()
        sumCol_a_df2 = df2['a'].sum()
        columnTotal_dict[name] = sumCol_a_df1 + sumCol_a_df2
    except ValueError:
        print("Data in this column are not of type int. Skipping")
```

Comment: i don't want to specify column name, bcz columns name are dynamic.. this will not work in my case.

Comment: You can get the column names in a list and then iterate over it to get the sum. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks Prashant for the solution.
 i preferd @sammywemmy solution it is more dynamic.

Comment: No problem @gaurav. Good thing is your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (assuming that the column `c` can be taken from the first data frame)

```py
>>> mask = ['a', 'b', 'd']
>>> df_out = df1[mask] + df2[mask]
>>> df_out['c'] = df1['c']
>>> df_out
   a  b  d   c
0  2  2  2  dd
1  2  2  2  ee
2  2  2  2  ff
```